# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to store the User.Identity.GetUserName() in a database and I have made a relationship between the RequirementData class and ApplicationUser and the database tables were created successfully but when I am storing the User.Identity.GetUserName() in RequirementData table it says the below error:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.RequirementData_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId". The conflict occurred in database "RequirementWorld", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.

Here is the MVC controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        ViewBag.TeamId = new SelectList(db.TeamNames, "TeamId", "TeamName");
        ViewBag.TechId = new SelectList(db.Teches, "TechId", "TechName");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "jobCode,positionName,skills,requiredSize,experience,jobDescription,uploadedBy,TechId,TeamId")] RequirementData requirementData)
    {
        var ApplicationUserId = UserManager.FindByEmail(User.Identity.GetUserName());
        requirementData.Id = ApplicationUserId.ToString();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.RequirementDatas.Add(requirementData);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.TeamId = new SelectList(db.TeamNames, "TeamId", "TeamName", requirementData.TeamId);
        ViewBag.TechId = new SelectList(db.Teches, "TechId", "TechName", requirementData.TechId);
        return View(requirementData);
    }
```

I want to store the current user name in the RequirementDatas table who created the record after logged in

Answer (score -1):

Update Sql Table Identity Specification "Yes", Identity Increment "1,1" and update entity.